# Oracle Hyperion - Planning - Forms

Tags: oracle, hyperion

I get this error when selecting already created forms in Hyperion Planning.

```
Unable to obtain a connection to Hyperion Essbase. If this problem persists, please contact your administrator.
```

I`m newbie to Hyperion. Please help to resolve this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error in *Oracle Hyperion* use to prompt if an User having privileges to perform a **cube refresh**. More the users logged in more the time it takes for the **cube refresh**.

Once all are done with creating forms it is good to carry out a member push (**cube refresh**) then you can overcome this issue.